# Not valid template file: mini.phtml and sidebar_header.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, error, log

Got error in my logs:

> CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/mini.phtml

and

> CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar_header.phtml

Should there be a `mini.phtml` template file? In my rwd theme I have `minicart.phtml` but still no `mini.phtml`, same with `sidebar_header.phtml`, I have `sidebar.phtml` in my rwd theme but no such a template like `sidebar_header.phtml`.

Any ideas?

grep result:

> /microcloud/domains/vamdev/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/includes/src/Amasty/Cart/controllers/AjaxController.php:176: $template = "checkout/cart/mini.phtml";
>
> /microcloud/domains/vamdev/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/local/Amasty/Cart/etc/config.xml:164: checkout/cart/mini.phtml
>
> /microcloud/domains/vamdev/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/local/Amasty/Cart/controllers/AjaxController.php:176: $template = "checkout/cart/mini.phtml";

Comment: using grep command check from where "sidebar_header.phtml" is set.

Comment: @Grzegorz, theme205k theme folder available in app/design/frontend/default/ ?

Comment: @Dhaval I have only `blank`, `default`, `iphone`, and `modern` in this location.

Comment: it means this mini.phtml and sidebar_header.phtml file recognize by xml layout but not available in your template file  , find this two file name in your theme layout file and remove that!!

Comment: I will have a search through to see if I can find anything and will let you know if found it.

Comment: I have used the grep method and nothing was found. @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Answer (score 1):

Magento check first templates in your `current package->theme`, if he can't find them here, he go to your `current package->default` if he can't find them here again, he try to go to get them in `base/default` what is called: **Fallback system**, in your case the templates are :

- `checkout/cart/mini.phtml`
- `/checkout/cart/sidebar_header.phtml`.

So check this templates in your theme, maybe you have change there path in the server or in your xml

Comment: I have checked all the themes, `current package -> theme`, `current package->default`, `base->default`, `rwd` theme too. There is no such a file with a name `mini.phtml` or `sidebar_header.phtml`.

Comment: you don't use there files ?

Comment: I don't think I do. I guess people would have troubles checking out but everything runs fine. It is just these two errors that make my log file huge. Also as it relates to checkout, it got me a bit worried.

Comment: Obliged, you call them somewhere, either in some xml or in some phtml, if everything is fine in your website, search this: `checkout/cart/mini.phtml` ans `checkout/cart/sidebar_header.phtml` in your instance and comment the block who call this, If everything is fine !

Comment: how can I call this out?

Comment: in xml : `<block type="block/type" name="name" template="checkout/cart/mini.phtml"/>` for exemple, then in phtml : `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('block/type')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/mini.phtml')->toHtml()` for exemple

Comment: I can't find it anywhere for some reason, I tired what you said and got this error on front end: `FATAL ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION SETTEMP‌​LATE() ON A NON-OBJECT IN /DOMAINS/DEV.VAMPIREVAPE.CO.UK/HTTP/APP/DESIGN/FRONTEND/BOILERPLATE/VAMPIREVAPE/TEMPLATE/CHECKOUT/ONEPAGE.PHTML ON LINE 30`

Comment: I didn't tell you to put this in a phtml !, you asked me how the templates are called in phtml and I have give you an example, so remove what you have add in your phtml

Comment: I see, so basically I need to search through all the xml files to see if `mini.phtml` or `sidebar_header.phtml` are included anywhere?

Comment: Yes, if you are connected with ssh, you do this: `grep -rni "checkout/cart/mini.phtml"`

Comment: I used this command but it seem to "freeze" for some time. I left it for like 15 min but nothing happens.

Comment: 15min ! wow, search in app/design/frontend

Comment: do I navigate to the directory and use the command or have to specify the path? Sorry never used grep command before.

Comment: when you connect to ssh, you do: cd app/design/frontend [enter], now you are in `app/design/frontend` and now you do : grep -rni "checkout/cart/mini.phtml"

Comment: I have more vhosts on my server :p just didn't know If you had to specify the path to dictionary in the command or just navigate to the place and run the command, it is running now in the front-end dictionary but it has been already for 5 min ...

Comment: still going... : `[frontend]$ grep -rni "checkout/cart/mini.phtml"` something wrong?...

Comment: Maybe you have some problem in your server, i don't if this one what you are looking for `grep -rni "checkout/cart/mini.phtml" app/design/frontend` or search directly in your IDE PHP storm for exemple

Comment: Hymm... I'm guessing something's up with my store. I can't process large orders in back-end too as it freezes.

Comment: Got it, see the updated question

Comment: Sorry, false alarm, it was when I was messing with before and didn't completely delete it. The command worked but the result it empty. Tired to find both `sidebar_header.phtml` and `mini.phtml`

Comment: Found this, user I was using had permissions denied for some directories. Here is the result in updated answer using grep. Should I be worried there is no template files, even tho it is being called out? Or just delete it off the files and not worry about it no more? :D

Comment: In principle, you must find the code that calls this template and delete it if you do not need it,  as you can't find it, you leave it as it is, or if you dont want the message appears, create the Path of the two templates in your theme and then you will not see the message ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably these errors are coming from custom modules which you are using in your Magento instance.

`sidebar_header.phtml` and `mini.phtml` template files are not coming with default Magento I believe.

So most probably you can suspect the custom module which would specifically work for some cart functionality. If such custom extensions are using by your Magento instance, then you need to check that module, particularly layout xml files in order to track them out.

Comment: How can I track it down? Is there any method to track it where it is coming from?